# C++11 condition inclusion controlling expression "types act as if same representation as"?

Tags: c++, c++11

In 16.1.4 (Conditional inclusion) of the C++ standard it says:

> For the purposes of this token conversion and evaluation all signed and unsigned integer types act as if they have the same representation as, respectively, intmax_t or uintmax_t.

I don't understand this.  What does it mean "act as if they have the same representation as"?

`integer-literals` are tokenized to a specific fundamental type depending on their value and suffix as explained in 2.14.2.2.

Is the 16.1.4 quote saying that their type is somehow "replaced" by `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`?  (Is this exactly equivilant to statically casting the integer literals to `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t`?)

Comment: My reading of that means that it must be casted to `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t` only if not casting will result in different behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically means that the preprocessor doesn't have to deal
with type information; it can do all of its integral arithmetic
in a single type.  Most of the time, it won't make a different,
but it does mean that something like `UINT_MAX + 1U` will result
in a very big number, where as outside of the preprocessor, it
will result in `0`.